# useing libimobiledevice to set iphone's ringtones

Tags: iphone, ringtone

I am using libimobiledevice to write a program named iRingtone. Hoping to set ringtones without iTunes.

Steps:

1. uploading .m4r  to /iTunes_Control/Ringtones/
2. update plist file /iTunes_Control/iTunes/Ringtones.plist

The ringtone can be preview under Settings->Sounds->Ringtone, but it CAN NOT be set as the ringtone. ****The system force it fallback to the default ringtone -- Opening(Default).**** 
Every time when i use iTools to set the ringtones, i can find that the size of **MediaLibrary.sqlitedb-wal** and **iTunesCDB** under /iTunes_Control/iTunes/ changed. But they are *binaries*.
So, does any one know the **correct format** of these two files. 
Or, These two files have nothing to do with ringtones, then how to correctly set the ringtones?

**Thanks a lot.**

Comment: do you plan on selling this on the Apple App Store?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann Of Course Not. I'm an opener. And this program is under Windows. This project is hosted at github named [imobile](https://github.com/chinat/imobile.git). Hope for your help!